# Issue configuring options in ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

While configuring Options on my project I came up across this error :

> System.InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[[myproject.Models.ConnectionStrings, ]'. Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor. Alternatively, give the 'optionsAccessor' parameter a non-null default value.

Any idea ?

*I configured the model as following :*

```
namespace myproject.Models
{
  public class ConnectionStrings
  {
    public ConnectionStrings()
    {
        AzureStorageConnectionString = "azurestorageconnectionstring_ctor";
    }
    public string AzureStorageConnectionString { get; set; }
  }
}
```

**Startup.cs ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) contains the following two lines**

```
services.AddOptions();
services.Configure<ConnectionStrings>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
```

**My controller contains this**

```
private ConnectionStrings _connectionStrings;
public IActionResult Index(IOptions<ConnectionStrings> optionsAccessor)
{
  _connectionStrings = optionsAccessor.Value;
  return View();
}
```

**And both my appsettings.json and appsettings.Development.json consist of the following**

```
{
 "Logging": {
 "LogLevel": {
   "Default": "Debug",
   "System": "Information",
   "Microsoft": "Information"
  }
 },
 "ConnectionStrings": {
   "AzureStorageConnectionString": "xxxxxxxxx"
 },
}
```

Comment: You're supposed to inject `IOptions<ConnectionStrings>` into the controller's constructor, not into the `Index()` action. By defining it as an action parameter, you're expecting the `ModelBinder` to construct it for you (and obviously, it cannot).

Comment: You could also just decorate the parameter with `[FromServices]` - i.e. `public IActionResult Index([FromServices] IOptions<ConnectionStrings> optionsAccessor)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're supposed to inject `IOptions<ConnectionStrings>` into the controller's *constructor*, not into the `Index()` method.

By defining it as an action parameter, you're expecting the `ModelBinder` to construct it for you (and obviously, it cannot).

See [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1)